# Kernel: getting command line and pid_parent in do_execve_common?

Tags: linux, kernel, execve

Is it possible to get the command line of a process that is about to be created in do_execve_common of the Linux kernel? In other words, how to extract the command line from argv and printk it to dmesg.

Secondly, is it also possible to get the pid and the parent pid of the process? Is this information available somewhere around do_execve_common?

I need to do those things ONLY in the kernel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think by the time calling do_execve, the pid & real_parent & comm fields in task_struct are already initialized.

So you can use kernel functions: getpid(), getppid() and get_task_comm() to get what you want. I am not sure these functions are there in your Linux Kernel version. If not, there should be some similar functions.

Comment: I don't think that it answers my question. For instance, getpid returns the pid of the current process, here I'm in the kernel. I want the pid of the process that is about to be created or has just been created. I would be OK to get the info at the last line of do_execve_common.

Comment: Apologize! The call is in the context of the process so sys_getpid can work. I still don't get all the arguments. I thought that this link http://www.mail-archive.com/kernelnewbies@nl.linux.org/msg00278.html would help but it's not working. Don't know why...

Comment: I will mark this answer though it only gives half of the solution (pid but not the arguments). I have opened another question for how to extract argv from linux_binprm: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15275594

Comment: @gregoiregentil "*getpid returns the pid of the current process, here I'm in the kernel*" ...in the context of the process calling `execve`. All of the system calls still take place in the context of a process, even though you're executing kernel code.